# .css, .js and .png files not found when opening Tracking URI in YARN

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, jobs

I can view a list of running jobs on YARN at this URI:

https://server1.company.com:8443/gateway/yarnui/yarn/apps/RUNNING

Further I can access job specific information by opening the TrackingUI:

https://server1.company.com:8443/gateway/yarnui/yarn/proxy/application_1481927689976_0178

[image: tracking UI link]

However, when I do this, I **only get the HTML document**, none of the other required .js, .css and .png files :

```
GET https://server.company.com:8443/gateway/yarnui/yarn/proxy/application_1481927689976_0178
200 OK (text/html)

GET https://server.company com:8443/proxy/application_1481927689976_0178/static/bootstrap.min.css
404 Not Found (text/html)
```

If I go directly to the server on which the job is running :

http://server2.company.com:8088/proxy/application_1481927689976_0178

Everything works fine:

```
GET http://server2.company.com:8088/proxy/application_1481927689976_0178
200 OK (text/html)

GET http://server2.company:8088/proxy/application_1481927689976_0178/static/bootstrap.min.css
200 OK (text/css)
```

Sounds like a YARN config issue – but I’ve set the yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address to the correct value:

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
  <value>server2.company.com:8088</value>
</property>
```

Any ideas why I can’t access these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM's support fix addresses this exact issue:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21980169